# adding a new property doesn't update doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have added the following property to one of my class:

```
/**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\Column(name="emailReminderSent", type="boolean")
     */
    private $emailReminderSent = false;

  /**
     * Set emailReminderSent
     *
     * @param boolean $emailReminderSent
     * @return InstagramShop
     */
    public function setEmailReminderSent($emailReminderSent)
    {
        $this->emailReminderSent = $emailReminderSent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailReminderSent
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getEmailReminderSent()
    {
        return $this->emailReminderSent;
    }
```

however when I do:

```
sudo php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

it doesn't add the emailReminderSent to the table. Any idea why doctrine is acting like this? I've tried clearing the cache so many times, but it didn't help.

My config looks something like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  utf8mb4
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver: memcached
                query_cache_driver: memcached
                result_cache_driver: memcached
                auto_mapping: true
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your metadatas are stored in Memcached, did you try to flush it ?

```
// Namespace\MyBundle\NamespaceMyBundle.php

public function boot()
{
    \Memcached::flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your mapping in Resources/config/doctrine to reflect these changes?

Comment: usually I don't have to add any mapping and running update force would just work

Comment: It's probably obvious and you've probably done it, but have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: I did mention that in my original post right, that I've did this over and over again (clearing the cache).

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, didn't see that before. Lack of concentration.